# Android Studio LibGDX issue with code repetition

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play

My game is almost fully working, however, I would like to create an endless level for my game, like Flappy Bird,This is the code that adds the enemy `collisionList.add(new collisionEntity(world, collsionTexture, 6, 1));` and this is the code that adds the floor `groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,10, 10 ,18));`  I would like these lines of code to repeat themselves like a loop without adding them over and over again, such as

```
`groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,10, 10 ,13));`

    groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,25, 10 ,20));
    groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,10, 7 ,12));
    groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,10, 10 ,16));
```

How do I do that? My game results like this`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql-Mr81fZ0U, Go to 2:23-2:31 minutes to see what I mean`

I just want it to add obstacles and repeat themselves over and over again and same goes with the ground code.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depend on what you want and how you want things to line up or rather randomized. If you understand that the `update()` method is called each frame you could have statements in it to check when you want to "spawn" something. It's also important to remove items from your list if you don't need them anymore so they can be collected by the garbage collector to free up memory. If you use disposable objects you should dispose these too.

One method could be a timer that keeps track of.... yes, time. When it reaches a certain time you spawn something (add to your list). Once your camera moves past a object you can remove it from your list.

```
float timer = 0;
float spawnTime = 4;
private void spawnEntity()
{
    //Increment timer by the duration since the previous frame
    timer += Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
    //Compare to spawntime
    if (timer >= spawnTime)
    {
        //Spawn your object
        groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,25, 10 ,20));            
        //But you will probably want to spawn something on the right, just outside of your screen view.

        //This is the right side of your vp in the world. Depending how you draw you can add some more to it.
        float spawnX = camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth / 2;
        //Then use this to spawn your object, since you hardcoded stuff I have no idea where to put it.

        //Now reset timer
        timer-= spawnTime;

        //And perhaps randomize the spawnTime? (between 2 and 4 seconds)
        spawnTime = random.nextFloat() * 2 + 2;
    }
}
```

Just call this each update loop. Currently it will add using your hardcoded numbers. `groundList.add(new groundEntity(world, groundTexture, overgroundTexture,overground2Texture ,25, 10 ,20));` so if 25, 10 or 20 takes care of positioning it will just overlay the entity. Put `float spawnX` in front of `groundlist.add(...)` and use spawnX as your X positioning. If you have a moving camera it will come in from the right. If you don't have a moving camera yet then add these two lines to your update for testing it out.

```
camera.position.x += 1;
camera.update();
```